# Extending Magento Model Not Working

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am trying to extend a community plugin and everything looks correct to me, but I must be missing something because my methods are not overriding the community plugins methods.

The odd thing is that I downloaded the [Modules Conflict Detector](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modules-conflict-detector.html) and it says it is my plugin is extending the community plugin just fine.

**app/etc/modules/KNG_M2eProMods.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <KNG_M2eProMods>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Ess_M2ePro/>
            </depends>
        </KNG_M2eProMods>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/KNG/M2eProMods/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <KNG_M2eProMods>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </KNG_M2eProMods>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <M2ePro>
                <rewrite>
                    <magento_payment>KNG_M2eProMods_Model_Magento_Payment</magento_payment>
                    <magento_quote>KNG_M2eProMods_Model_Magento_Quote</magento_quote>
                    <magento_order>KNG_M2eProMods_Model_Magento_Order</magento_order>
                </rewrite>
            </M2ePro>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/KNG/M2eProMods/Model/Magento/Order.php**

```
class KNG_M2eProMods_Model_Magento_Order extends Ess_M2ePro_Model_Magento_Order
{
    private function placeOrder()
    {
     ......
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/KNG/M2eProMods/Model/Magento/Payment.php**

```
class KNG_M2eProMods_Model_Magento_Payment extends Ess_M2ePro_Model_Magento_Payment
{
    protected $_code = 'payment_profile';
}
```

**app/code/local/KNG/M2eProMods/Model/Magento/Quote.php**

```
class KNG_M2eProMods_Model_Magento_Quote extends Ess_M2ePro_Model_Magento_Quote
{
    private function initializeQuoteItems()
    {
     ......
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet from the config.xml of the plugin I am trying to extend.
**app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/etc/config.xml**

```
......
<models>
        <M2ePro>
            <class>Ess_M2ePro_Model</class>
            ......
        </M2ePro>
        ......
</models>
......
```

Here are the file paths I am extending.

```
app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Magento/Order.php
app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Magento/Payment.php
app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Magento/Quote.php
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: private functions are not inheritable if that's what you're trying to do

Comment: @subroutines I am actually trying to override the private functions. I thought you could still override them. Am I wrong in that?

Comment: No, you can't do that. That's why they're specified as private. You'll need to change their scope to protected in the parent class.

Comment: @subroutines I guess that would explain it. instead of of changing the scope of the parent class we will just modify the parent class. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your config.xml is **not** set properly. Magento is **case sensitive** in reading the xml files. So your config.xml file should be like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <KNG_M2eProMods>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </KNG_M2eProMods>
  </modules>
  <global>

    <models>
      <m2epromods>
        <class>KNG_M2eProMods_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>m2epromods_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </m2epromods>
            <m2epro>
                <rewrite>
                    <magento_order>KNG_M2eProMods_Model_M2ePro_Magento_Order</magento_order>
                </rewrite>
            </m2epro>
            <m2epro>
                <rewrite>
                    <magento_payment>KNG_M2eProMods_Model_M2ePro_Magento_Payment</magento_payment>
                </rewrite>
            </m2epro>
            <m2epro>
                <rewrite>
                    <magento_quote>KNG_M2eProMods_Model_M2ePro_Magento_Quote</magento_quote>
                </rewrite>
            </m2epro>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

Please comment here if you have any doubt.

Comment: Are you talking about the m2epro being uppercase bs being lower. Mine version is mixed case like "M2ePro" because the plugin I am overriding is using that same exact mixed case. As shown in the code snippet of the app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/etc/config.xml file.

Comment: I also was wondering why you have a helpers. I am not using helpers at all. Those are not required are they?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't noticed. In you case helper is not needed. I have removed now.